# Heroku app not pulling S3 images on other machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, amazon-s3, heroku

I recently added photo uploading to a web application that I'm hosting on heroku.  I'm using S3 for storage and it's working great, however when other users go onto the site, they see a photo missing icon rather than the photo.  On my machine however, I see the photos on the site.  Any clues as to what is happening?  Thanks!

Comment: Are your S3 permissions on the bucket/files set appropriately? It sounds like you might have it restricted in a way that allows you to see it and not whomever else you have viewing (e.g. by IP address).

Comment: There are only four options: list, upload/delete, view permissions, edit permissions.  I'm not sure which of these will allow anyone to see the images on the website.  I'm still very new to S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload your photos to s3 you need to set their access level to public using whatever s3 lib your using.

Here's snippet from s3 api docs:

> x-amz-acl 
>   The canned ACL to apply, to the object
>   that is created after completing
>   multipart upload. For more
>   information, go to REST Access Policy
>   in the Amazon S3 Developer Guide.
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: private
>
> Valid Values: private | public-read |
>   public-read-write | authenticated-read
>   | bucket-owner-read |
>   bucket-owner-full-control

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadInitiate.html

Comment: I'm using carrierwave and fog, and in the initializer I have config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
 config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave'
 
 config.fog_credentials = {
  :provider  => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id => 'ACCESSKEY',
  :aws_secret_access_key  => 'SECRETKEY'
 }
 
 config.fog_directory = 'BUCKETNAME'
 config.fog_public = true

Comment: When I view the source of the page and click on the image link, firefox brings up a page saying this connection is untrusted and that the certificate is invalid.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I figured it out, I wasn't storing the correct url, I thought it was the carrierwave uploader's .url method, but it actually was something different when I looked on S3.  I changed it to the format of S3 and it worked perfectly!

Comment: CarrierWave was doing the bucketname followed by the standard s3 stuff, but when I looked on S3 it said it was the reverse.